# How to make java rest api return multiple json objects

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm creating a REST Service in JAva, and below is the code part:

```
@GET
@Path("/getsummary")
@Produces("application/json")

public Response summary()
{

        VoltDAOImpl voltDao = new VoltDAOImpl();
        Map<String ,List<HashMap<String,String>>> returnList=       voltDao.getOrderDetails("PEAKM" , "Hydra" ,
                 "" ,  voltDao.client,"notional" ,1000);
        List<HashMap<String,String>> totalSlpSummaryList = returnList.get("total_slp_summary");
        List<HashMap<String,String>> totalSlpSummaryBySideList = returnList.get("total_slp_summary_by_side");
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

            String json1 = null;
            String json2 = null;
            try {
                json1 = ow.writeValueAsString(totalSlpSummaryList);
                json2 = ow.writeValueAsString(totalSlpSummaryBySideList);
                System.out.println(json1);
                System.out.println(json2);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    return Response.status(200).entity(json1).build();
}
```

Right now, the above is only returning json1 object but I want it to return both json1 and json2. How do I achieve that?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, obviously. If you say you return JSON you need to return **valid** JSON. For example, wrap the objects into an array.

Comment: Make a list of the objects you are trying to return, and then return just that.

Comment: build a DTO object and include json1 and json2 into it and return this DTO

Comment: @PaoloMastrangelo Json string

Comment: Ok sorry i have delete the comment because i have understand it before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String bothJson = "["+json1+","+json2+"]"; //Put both objects in an array of 2 elements
return Response.status(200).entity(bothJson).build();
```

or

```
String bothJson = "["+json1+","+json2+"]"; //Put both objects in an array of 2 elements
return Response.getWriter().write(bothJson);
```

or

```
String[] str = new String[2];
str[0] = json1;
str[1] = json2;
return Response.status(200).entity(str).build();
```

Try this, the concept is create a matrix/array and send it.